# Angular ui-router show/hide elements on specific state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to show/hide specific content depending on the state of my angular app. But it apparently only works on "childstates"...

I tried to do this:

```
function($scope, $rootScope, $state){
     $rootScope.$state = $state;
}
```

and then my html:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK - ELEMENT REMAINS HIDDEN!!!             
<div data-ng-show="$state.includes('home')">some content...</div>

// THIS WORKS - ELEMENT IS VISIBLE ON STATE!!
<div data-ng-show="$state.includes('artist.videos')">some content...</div>
```

So, my question is: why doesnt it work on the `'home'` state??

What is the issue here?

Comment: could you share us the state configuration of *home* and *artist* ? And what look like your URL on your test case

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with scope inheritance. Check out the following link:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Specifically:

"This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models

Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use 
 rather than 
."

Comment: Not true, $state work with `artist.videos` and not with `home` this have nothing to do with dot notation because we're referring to state name, not scope variable.